# 1: White space above header and div, Normalize and margin:0 didn't fix. 2: Adjusting columns

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble figuring out 2 problems I am hoping I could get some help with.

Problem 2 I am still looking into, but I threw it inn here in case someone had a quick solution.

Here is my jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/zf0ecsnp/5/

#### Problem 1

I can't seem to figure out what creates a small row/area of white space above my div's and header.

When running it in jsfiddle it's not there, but when I open my index.html file in my browser it's there.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrAoa.jpg

I've tried adding this to my CSS, but that just messed everything up:

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Normalize.css also didn't take care of it.

I tried this as well for both h2 and div

```
h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

But it didn't fix it.

#### Problem 2

I want the header (Header 1, Header 2, Header 3 over 2 lines) and the box surrounding the column be as long as the longest header and/or box.

I tried playing around with margin-top and bottom 100% and -100% and overflow:hidden, but that removed the bottom border.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question I wasn't able to recreate the issue. I'm not getting any white space [image: image Attached]

And for your second question you can use something called Grid.

```
 grid-template-rows:    minmax(100px, auto); 
 grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 50%) 1fr 3em;
```

links more more information https://learncssgrid.com/#grid-container

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
    body {margin: 0;}

this is because of default browser margin